# Derivative at end point of a interval

Tags: calculus, derivatives, rolles-theorem

While studying Rolle's Theorem, a question came in my mind that *can there exist a function which is continuous in the interval [a,b]
and differentiable in the interval (a,b) but not differentiable at either one of the end points of the interval [a,b]?*

Comment: the top half of a circle:  $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: $f(x) = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{1 - x}$ in $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Idea with non infinite derivative from $x \sin \frac {1}{x}$ at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

of course let me show you an example.
$$f: [1,2] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}. $$

$$f(x) = \sqrt{(1-x)(x-2)}.$$

This function is clearly continuos in $[1,2]$ and differentiable in $(1,2)$ but using the limit definition of differentiation in $1,2$ the limit does not converges.